# Is there any way in Eclipse to format a code that contains divs in the way Netbeans do it?

Tags: eclipse, html, code-formatting

Is there any way in Eclipse to format a code that contains divs in the way Netbeans do it?

I mean, if you have this in Netbeans:

```
<div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
```

and you format it (Source > Format), it becomes this way:

```
<div>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: to clarify... you're saying it fixes the nesting of tags... not just the indentation?

Comment: no, i'm just refering to the indentation.

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut you'll need is: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

That works for HTML, CSS, PHP, XML, JS and so on. But you need to have a PHP, HTML editor/plugin like Aptana, PDT or WTP.

Comment: Hi Kau-Boy, when i press that shortcut all the lines just go the the first column. When I go to "About Eclipse" i have this: Eclipse for PHP Developers.

Build id: 20090920-1017.

Comment: Are you sure you opened the HTML file with the PDT HTML Editor? As I use Aptana I am not sure if the PDT editors supports formating but I would bet, that it does support it!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can if:

- you have the **[WTP plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)** (Web Tools Platform) installed
- you have unselected the "Automatically remove End tags" option, then you have the formatting experience you want.

[image: http://web.archive.org/web/20130402053202/http://img534.i_mageshack.us/img534/324/eclipsexmlempty.png]

Comment: but im not using Java, jut PHP.

Comment: @user248959: WTP is not just for Java web server. If you need to edit xml files and format them accordingly, you need WTP.